# IF Function/VLOOKUP Combo

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup, formulas

So this seems like it should be pretty easy. I could just concatenate and make another column in the data to make a unique combo and get my answer. But that just seems so messy. So here I am reaching out to you fine folks to pick your brains.

I want to look up HQLine and Description in the MPCC tab to return the correct MPCC Code. I tried a couple IF statements with VLOOKUPS but couldn't get it right.

So I need to look up BK3 Positive Crankcase Ventilation (PCV) Connector in the MPCC tab. So it needs to match BK3 and the Long description and then give me the correct code.

Here is the missing data file
[image]

Here is the MPCC export list that I want to search
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUMIFS`.

`SUMIFS` will find the sum in a table of rows that meet certain criteria. If the MPCC is always a number, and the MQAb-LongDescription is always unique, `SUMIFS` will find the correct ID.

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C$2:C$100,Sheet1!A$2:A$100,A2,Sheet1!B$2:B$100,B2)
```

where `Sheet1!A$2:A$100` is the **HQAb** data, `Sheet1!B$2:B$100` is the **Long Description** data, `Sheet1!C$2:C$100` is the **MPCC Number data**, `A2` is the **HQLine**, and `B2` is the **Description**.

The formula would go in `C1`.

[More information on VLookup with Multiple Criteria](http://www.excel-university.com/vlookup-on-two-or-more-criteria-columns/)

Comment: Though, I would personally just use a helper column and a simple `VLookup`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Index/Match with multiple criteria.

I'm assuming that you will put this formula in "Sheet1", cell C2, and your lookup data is in a sheet called "Sheet2", columns A, B, C from row 2 to 30.

Put this in Sheet1, C2:

`=INDEX(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$30,MATCH(A2&B2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$30&Sheet2!$B$2:$B$30,0))`
(Enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>) and drag down.)

Adjust the ranges as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

lets assume your first Table is on sheet 1 in the range A1:C11 and the MPCC codes are located on Sheet 2 in the range A1:C32.  Each table has a header row so your data really starts in row 2.

Similar to BruceWayne's answer of using an array formula, you can bring the array calculation inside of a formula and avoid the special array treatment.  There are a few functions that can do this.  I will demonstrate with the SUMPRODUCT function;

On Sheet 1, Cell C2, use the following formula:

```
 =INDEX('Sheet 2'!$C$1:C$32,SUMPRODUCT((A2='Sheet 2'!$A$2:A$32)*(B2='Sheet 2'!$B$2:B$32)*row('Sheet 2'!$A$2:A$32))
```

Explanation:

When the value in A2 matches the value in the range in the second sheet it will be true and false when it does not.  when True False get used in math operations they are treated at 1 and 0 respectively.  Therefore  the only result from your two search criteria will be the rows where A2 match is true and B2 match is true and this will have a value of 1.  The 1 will then be multiplied by the row number.  Since all other results will be 0 since your list is a unique combination, the sum part of sumproduct will sum up to the row number where your unique row is located.  This in turn is used by the indext function to return the row to give your unique number.